# Can I create an enum that has more than 500 members?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums

I am creating a database system where there are tables that have some data that are not user derived, they will be used by the app for lookup mainly. But for the database performance and query optimization I decided to use enums for these lookups and store their ints in the table instead of the entire word.

I want to make an enum called diseases and they are 500 types.

So, can I create an enum in C# (.net core) that has 500 members and, if not, how can I achieve such thing? Also, is there a way to localize the values in enums?

I use the enums because they will save me the joining when I make queries in database. If I didn't use enums I would have to query a table then make 2 joins with another 2 tables that have the lookup data. If I make them with enums though, I only need the number which will be saved in the first table and in the app get its string and I will save the query from using 2 joins every time I get the data.

Comment: Don't use enums for data you are storing in the database. otherwise, any change of data means recompiling.

Comment: `So, can I create an enum in C# (.net core) that has 500 members` What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @mjwills nothing happened but i found that they might triple in the future to 1500 max so i decided to ask if this is applicable or not . as i see all enums on internet example as small ones with few members

Comment: `every time I get the data.` Why would you need to do it **every time**? Could you not use a `ConcurrentDictionary`to store the `int` and `string` values the first time you need them?

Comment: Are you going to take the time to publish **a new version** of your application every single time a new value is added to the table? That's what would happen if you used an enum

Comment: A JSON file with 1500 items is pretty much nothing nowadays

Comment: @ZoharPeled thats what i am going to do instead of enums

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i will use xml in .net core anyway the same as json :) thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I create an enum in C# (.net) that has 500 members

Sure, if you want to.
But I think it's a bad idea. Imagine if someone else wants to use your Database, they'll then have to have a copy of the same `enum`, which means you'll have to maintain 2 (or more) copies of the same list as long as other people need it and I don't think anyone wants to do that.

500 rows in a Database is like nothing, making it into an `enum` won't help you that much (at least not something you can notice), instead just store them in a Table and everyone is happy.

> Is there a way to localize the values in enums

No, not out-of-the-box. You will have to create your own solution for this. It depends on where and how your localizations are stored.

Comment: but i use the enums because they will save me the joining when i make queries in database , if i didnt use enums i will have to query a table then make 2 joins with another 2 tables that have the lookup data. but if i make them with enums i only need the number which will be saved in the first table and in the app get its string and i will no neeed use 2 joins . and saving ints is better for database size and quering than strings am i right or no ? what should i do ?

Comment: You are right, one smallint field is less than 2 fields (Id, string) but you have to think beyond of just this. Is your app the only thing that will use the database? Will the enum change frequently (making you update the app everytime)?

Comment: the app has to save all diseases that are known and we don't have all of them so yes it will require frequent changes that why i thought of configs at first time with the project but asked on SO and said 1500 in config are too big !! which i dont get it . however if config can work with me they will have the solution of localization .

Comment: Then you'll definetly want a table for this, your table can even contain the localized diseases names and stuff.

Comment: ok so i use the table instead of enums and make colomn for each language to be localized and only call that table of lookups once as mentioned by@mjwills and save the result in a dict or client side so i don't query them again . is that okay ?

Comment: Yes, that's how I would do it too. Also, you can save only the language the user wants in the dict so you can get rid of the other languages/columns.

Comment: I disagree with the premise of the answer. If someone wants to use the database they can still use it provided that the table exists and it should exist even if there is an enum to validate the constraint via a foreign key. That being said diseases is a terrible thing to put in an enum so in this case please go for an entity.